# What is this bullet-shaped part in dehydrator?

Tags: identification, components, heat

[image: strange part]

I am trying to figure out why my dehydrator stops heating after random amounts of time. My assumption is, that it is somehow related to this bullet-shaped part with a green tip, which connects the heating element to neutral.

I guess it might be some thermistor, but I didn't find anything looking like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a thermal fuse. Typically they have a temperature and maximum current marked on them.

The purpose is safety- to protect against a fire when excessive temperature is sensed it can open permanently and prevent disaster.

Unlikely to be the cause of intermittent operation. Look elsewhere. I would look for a relay with worn-out contacts or a failing power supply capacitor. If it's not electronic then likely the bimetal thermostat is the culprit (perhaps attached to a knob for setting the temperature).

Comment: That seems to be it! you are also correct in that it probably is not the culprit, as I could measure no voltage across it when the heating element turned off. Interestingly it immediately heats after turning it off/on again; so maybe some issue with the bimetallic strip. I might open another question with a rev eng schematic, should I get nowhere

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, that's seems like a non-resettable thermal fuse, so that seems unlikely to be the culprit. If there is a temperature sensor somewhere, though, that would be a good next thing to check.  Thermistors, etc. will connect to some electronics, rather than directly to the heater circuit. A thermostat would be in the power circuit (series with the heater) though, and they can cause intermittents.  Simple bimetallic ones sometimes become flaky.  Hydraulic ones (remote sensing bulb) can develop dirty / worn contacts that can cause intermittent failures.   Good luck, hope it pans out!

Answer (score 0):

That's a thermal fuse or thermal cutoff, as seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_cutoff). They have a temperature at which they open and cut power to the heating elements. Some reset once the temperature drops below their reset point. I don't think the one you've pointed out will reset. It'll need to be replaced.